# Is there a hashing algorithm that has less collisions than DJB2?

Tags: algorithm, hash, hashtable

I am using the xor version of the djb algorithm to hash names. I did some quick googling before starting and found that this was a pretty common algorithm to use for this case. When testing my my code, I end up with what I think are a large amount of collisions.

I ran a couple of different lists of names against the algorithm and I found that depending on the list of names I would have on the low end 50% collisions and on the high end as much as 96.9% of the names colliding. These collisions do occur after performing the modulo operation on the resulting hash to make it fit in a table. Is this par for the course when it comes to the non cryptographic hashing algorithms? Or am I doing something wrong / picking the wrong hashing algorithm.

Edit:
I am using an open addressing scheme with linear probing. I use a prime number as my table size and I resize the table by choosing the smallest prime larger than double the previous size. I resize the table when it is 60% filled.

Comment: I added the information. Let me know if there is still important information missing.

Comment: https://github.com/rurban/smhasher/

Comment: It is very, very unlikely that you are getting that collision rate for djb2. Most likely you have mis-implemented it or you actually have a huge number of duplicates in your name lists.

Comment: For comparison, I inserted 6000 values using a CRC32 hash (generated using `__builtin_ia32_crc32si` [see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/gcc/X86-Built-in-Functions.html)] into 10000 buckets and counted how often I linearly probed to the subsequent buckets during insertions: just under 4000 times.  I don't know how you counted your 96.9%, but if you take a measurement like mine and get far more than 4000 then yeah, your hash function sucks.  My C++ insert code: `size_t h = hash(t) % v_.size(); while (v_[h] != unused_) { ++collisions_; if (++h == v_.size()) h = 0; } v_[h] = t;`